# Can I install a 60A branch circuit breaker in a 60A sub-panel?

Tags: electrical-panel

I am connecting a kiln which requires a 60 amp circuit to a sub-panel. The sub-panel is off the 100 amp main fed by a 60 amp breaker. Do I need to increase the sub panel breaker size or is as is ok?

Comment: Can you post information about the other loads in the area served by this subpanel?

Comment: Specifically, what other loads might be running from the sub-panel while the kiln is running? Nuisance trips in the middle of a firing are no fun, but if you had (let's dream big) a pug mill that you strictly would not turn on while the kiln was firing (and vice versa) that would be fine. And if you increase the breaker size, you very likely need to replace the wire with larger wire (or, possibly, run a new circuit from the main just for the kiln and leave the sub-panel wiring alone.)

Comment: Does the sub-panel have a main breaker in it, or is it lugs-only?

Comment: How long are your firing times? If less than 3 hours you may be able to run the kiln if the other loads are very small but if over 3 hours the wiring needs to be 125% so the sub would be two small.

Comment: The kiln will generally run at night with nothing but lights on the panel. The sub panel has a 60amp main breaker. I thought in this instance I would go to 80 amp with appropriate wire. The kiln and 60 amp breaker require 6-2 with ground. The box is rated for 125.

Comment: Does this sound ok to you guys?